# Mythtv user jobs prior to commercial flagging jobs?

Tags: mythtv

I would like my Mythtv user jobs to execute prior to commercial flagging jobs. Is there a setting for this?

Background: I have a user job that sends a dent to my Identi.ca account when a recording is finished. Since I'm doing commercial flagging the dent is delayed until the commercial flagging is finished. How can I get my user job in the queue ahead of the commercial flagging job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved mythcommflag to a user job. I positioned it after my Identi.ca user job. Now the dent is created before the commercial flagging user job starts. Thanks to @justinblah on Twitter for this tip.